# How to a reference an HTML element with id+class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In the following javascript/html, I can reference **div.answer** but how do I reference **div#flashcard-001.answer**?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="flashcard-001" class="flashcard">
    <div class="question">What color is the sky?</div>
    <div class="answer">blue</div>
    <button class="show">Show</button>
    <button class="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//run when page is loaded
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $("div.answer").hide(); //WORKS
    $("div#flashcard-001.answer").hide(); //DOES NOT WORK
    $("button.show").bind("click", function(e) {
        $("div.answer").show();
    });
    $("button.hide").bind("click", function(e) {
        $("div.answer").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a space:

```
$("div#flashcard-001 .answer").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

$("#flashcard-001").children(".answer").hide();

Comment: +1 This solution is more efficient than `$("div#flashcard-001 .answer")` or `$("#flashcard-001 .answer")`.

Comment: @Jourkey: No, it really is since jQuery evaluates the selector from the right to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to select a descendant of the DIV element with the ID *flashcard-001*, you need the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) or – since your element is also a direct child – the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors):

```
div#flashcard-001 .answer
div#flashcard-001 > .answer
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer most div has a full selector of:

```
div#flaschard-001.flashcard
```

not:

```
div#flashcard-001.answer
```

I believe you are simply using the wrong selector.