# How can several HTML elements be referred to, for use in javascript/jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an issue with my code, because I usually use (for buttons, for example) an ID to refer to the element, such as:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.delete_imgs').click(function () {
         id = $(this).attr('id');
         $('.confirm_delete').css({
             visibility: "visible"
         });
     });
 });
```

So the above being, if any of the `.delete_imgs` buttons are click, then perform the function. And also using the `this` function to *refer* to the element being clicked on in the HTML document.

The above `id`'s are from a php function here:

```
                while($stmt -> fetch()){
                    echo "<tr><td>
<img class='delete_imgs' id='$matchid' src='Images/delete_icon.png'>
<img class='edit_imgs' id='$matchid'src='Images/edit_icon.png'></td>
                            <td>$hero</td>
                            <td>$result</td>
                            <td>$gamemode</td>
                            <td>$mmr</td>
                            </tr>";         
                }
```

This was fine before the `edit_imgs` image was added, because all of the `delete_imgs` would have a different ID (the match ID is unique). However now, I shouldn't have BOTH the edit and delete images with the same ID, so I'm not sure how I can refer to them for a javascript/jQuery function.

I apologise if this is quite a broad question, I can add more information if necessary:

**A shorter version of the question: How do you refer to several HTML element without using ID's or Classes?**

Edit: Here is what I will eventually be using the ID for:

```
function deletematch(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/RemoveMatch.php", //This code sends the variable with the match
        data: "match_id=" + id,  //id in it to the php file and executes the deletion.
        success: function(){
            alert("The match has been deleted");
            $('.confirm_delete').css({visibility:"hidden"});
        }
     });
}
```

The editmatch isn't coded yet.

Comment: You may specify multiple matches in jquery selector: `$('.delete_imgs, .edit_img')`

Comment: @Hindmost The problem however, is that I need to make 2 seperate functions that execute based on whether you click the "delete" image or the "edit" image. Both of those functions need to have an important variable, the "id" variable, which refers to the data that they are subsequently deleting/editing. The way I was giving them that variable, was with ID's/Classes, but I can't do that without having duplicated ID's, It seems.

Comment: You may use duplicated IDs, this is not deprecated.

Comment: @Hindmost Yes but from what I've learned, using duplicated ID's is not recommended and probably means I can do it a better way. That's why I'm posting here!

Comment: IDs should be unique, don't say "you may use duplicated IDs" as it is bad design. make the ID unique and use it only once, if it applies to all elements in that row then make the row have an ID which is unique... Alternatively store it in "data-id" attribute which is just data to help you perform your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the data attribute instead of "id". That way they can both share the same ID without having to break standards. Note that I'm assuming "delete_imgs" and "edit_imgs" have their own style so I have avoided altering those.

```
 while($stmt -> fetch()){
     echo "<tr><td>
         <img class='delete_imgs' data-id='$matchid' src='Images/delete_icon.png'>
         <img class='edit_imgs' data-id='$matchid'src='Images/edit_icon.png'></td>
         <td>$hero</td>
         <td>$result</td>
         <td>$gamemode</td>
         <td>$mmr</td>
     </tr>";         
 }
```

You can then get the ID in your JS like so:

```
 $('.delete_imgs').click(function () {
     id = $(this).data('id');
 });
```

You can also select both of them:

```
$('[data-id="id-goes-here"]').click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

However if you want a simple way to refer to both of them without knowing the ID, I would add another data attribute or a class. For example

```
// You can use the selector above: $('[data-type="action"]')
<img class='delete_imgs' data-type="action" data-id='$matchid' src='Images/delete_icon.png'>
<img class='edit_imgs' data-type="action" data-id='$matchid'src='Images/edit_icon.png'>
```

Or

```
// Select with: $('.action')
<img class='delete_imgs action' data-id='$matchid' src='Images/delete_icon.png'>
<img class='edit_imgs action' data-id='$matchid'src='Images/edit_icon.png'>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I like the data-type idea, I'll test it. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, when you have more than one element, you should use class.

```
           while($stmt -> fetch()){
                echo "<tr><td>
                        <img class='delete_imgs '".$matchid." src='Images/delete_icon.png'>
                        <img class='delete_imgs '".$matchid." src='Images/edit_icon.png'></td>
                        <td>$hero</td>
                        <td>$result</td>
                        <td>$gamemode</td>
                        <td>$mmr</td>
                        </tr>";         
            }
```

Now you're able to use `$(.delete_imgs.desiredMatchId)`

You also can use both like this:

```
$(img.class.class)
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you can refer SPECIFICALLY to one of the two classes? Is that what you demonstrated with `$(img.class.class)`? Perhaps that could be my solution if so.

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean

Comment: Ok so just to summarise quickly (sorry I'm quite new to coding), if you have the element `<div class="1 2"></div>` and a div `<div class="1 3"></div>`, and then use `$(div.1.2)`. you're only referring to the former div and not the latter?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.delete_imgs').click(function(){
            id = $(this).attr('id'); 
            $('.confirm_delete').css({visibility:"visible"});
        });

        $('.edit_imgs').click(function(){
            id = $(this).attr('id'); 
            // do your edit work here
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same ID for two elements is not advisable in HTML. Append some counter after the id like

```
<img class='delete_imgs' id='$matchid + _counter' src='Images/delete_icon.png'>
<img class='edit_imgs' id='$matchid + _counter'src='Images/edit_icon.png'>
```

For your scenario refer like,

```
$('img.delete_imgs').click(function() {
   //Your logic goes here
});

$('img.edit_imgs').click(function() {
   //Your logic goes here
});
```

or

```
 $('img.delete_imgs, img.edit_imgs').click(function() {
     //Your logic goes here
});
```

Comment: The problem with the `id='$matchid + _counter'` is that I'm eventually using the ID to tell my PHP script with Ajax that I want all rows where ID = $matchid to be deleted/edited. Wouldn't the counter mess with that?

Comment: In that case directly append a string and change the attribute as class.

Comment: What you are doing with the ID? I don't see any usage of it in your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

try this i guess it will work....[example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481912/how-to-a-reference-an-html-element-with-idclass-in-jquery)

```
$('img#matchid .delete_img').click(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this :

```
function clickFunction(){
    if(this.alt == 'delete'){
        ...
    }
    if(this.alt == 'edit'){
        ...
    }
};
```

And then give your buttons alt value "delete" or "edit".